# Compare 2 dataframes, find matching rows, then sum a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

```
df1:
a   b   c   d   e   f
a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  1
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  5
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  3
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  5
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  4
a3  b3  c3  d3  e3  2
a4  b4  c4  d4  e4  4

df2:
a   b   c   d   e   g
a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  g0
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  g1
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  g2
```

I would like to compare columns `a, b, c, d` of the 2 dataframes, and if they match, sum the corresponding values in column f of df1 and add that column to df2. So in this case, I would get the resulting dataframe, where `h` is the sum of the appropriate `f` values:

```
a   b   c   d   e   g   h
a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  g0  1
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  g1  10
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  g2  7
```

`df1` is much bigger than `df2`, so I was thinking I could first get the matching rows from `df1`, then sum column `f` of this smaller dataframe, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: also `e` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with aggregate `sum`, I think you need also merge by `e` column:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b','c','d','e'])
         .groupby(['a','b','c','d','e','g'], as_index=False)
         .sum())
print (df)
    a   b   c   d   e   g   f
0  a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  g0   1
1  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  g1  10
2  a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  g2   7
```

Comment: I want to keep the values of e in df2 only. Would this still work?

Comment: Do you want merge by e column too?

Comment: No, I just want to keep the e column in df2, and the e column in df1 can be dropped. Basically just keep the entire df2 with the addition of f column.

Comment: @Rayne - So need `df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b','c','d','e'])` change to `df1[['a','b','c','d','f']].merge(df2, on=['a','b','c','d'])` - it means select columns from `df1` from list for `on` parameter + added new columns like `f` here?